# post-treatment of silicon surface after silanisation

Tags: organic-chemistry, everyday-chemistry, experimental-chemistry, biochemistry

I recently attempted to make a silicon oxide surface hydrophobic using trimethoxyoctylsilane and methanol as a solvent in ambient air conditions. I left the silicon in the solution for 24 hours, but after rinsing the surface with ethanol and pure water, the surface is still not clean. (I even rinsed it with methanol, water, and ethanol.)I have two questions:

1. Will I receive a hydrophobic surface if I reduce the silanisation time from 24 hours to just 5 minutes? I read somewhere that a maximum of 5 minutes is enough to achieve a hydrophobic surface.
2. How can I effectively clean the silicon after silanisation to receive a clean surface?

Comment: Surface should be treated *before* silanization.